# Javascript Add minutes to date not working in IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, datetime, safari

I want to add minutes to a date and display it.I am using the following code

```
    function dt(){
 var d = new Date();
 d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()+15*60);
            var theDate = d.getFullYear() + '-' + ( d.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + d.getDate()+' '+d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
            //var d1 = new Date( Date.parse( theDate ) + s1*60*1000 );      
            var d1=new Date(theDate);
            var hours = d1.getHours();
            var minutes = d1.getMinutes();
            var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
            hours = hours % 12;
            hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
            var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ';
            var t=( d1.getMonth() + 1 )+ '/' + d1.getDate()  + '/' + d1.getFullYear()  +'  '+strTime;  alert(t+ampm);
        }
        dt();
```

This code is working fine in Chrome.But in IE and safari, it was returning NAN:NAN:NAN 12:NAN AM.

Anyone please help.

Regards
Rekha

Comment: It seems the wrong DateTime format when executing the `var d1=new Date(theDate);`

Comment: Why even bother creating a new date the same as `d`? Just use `d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()+15*60);
```

will add 15 hours to the date. Why not:

```
d.setHours(d.getHours()+15);
```

Then you copy a date by creating a string then parsing it:

```
var theDate = d.getFullYear() + '-' + ... + d.getSeconds();
var d1 = new Date(theDate);
```

Do not do that. Ever. Parsing date strings is unreliable (as you've discovered) and not recommended. To copy a date, use:

```
var d1 = new Date(+d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
var d1 = new Date(theDate);
```

with:

```
var d1 = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds());
```

Using the [Date contructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) with a date string has some limitations

Comment: Please note that your function is quite verbose and isn't actually returning something.